# How can I define another activity's button?

Tags: android, junit, android-activity

As my project has multiple activities, how can I use another activity's
button or edittext in one class? For example, I have to type username
and password in order to login, then it change to another activity,
which means

```
private currentactivity nActivity;
```

and

```
login = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(activity.R.id.login);
username = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(activity.R.id.userName);
passward = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(activity.R.id.password);
```

So, now I have to test the next activity,how can I define the button?
I try to add in the same class:

```
private nextactivity nActivity;
```

and

```
friendlist = (Button)  nActivity.findViewById(activity.R.id.friendlist);
```

However,it seems that eclipse doesn't allow to use friendlist button.

Comment: You can define, or better said, reference, all the components that are present in the layout that you set using the setContentView() method.

Comment: Yes. currentactivity and nextactivity are different classes @keyser

Comment: I was confused by the non-capitalized names :p It's convention to start class names with a capital letter. For a second there I thought you had some serious syntax issues.

Comment: sorry, it should be private currentactivity mActivity; @keyser

Comment: @Chung : You can not access one `Activity` from another. If you need to pass data between two activities then use the `Intent` extras in the `Intent` used to start the other `Activity`. Either that or use `SharedPreferences` to save data that can be accessed from anywhere in your app.

Comment: but why do you want to use another activity's button from the current activity? you should explain your question better

Comment: As I use currentactivity to login on order to start nextactivity, I cannot start nextactivity without login. @belen

Comment: so in the currentactivity, the login is shown and therefore the login should be performed in this activity. If the login is ok, then you can start the nextactivity so you don't need the login view at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setContentView(yourPreviousActivityLayout)` and declare again your views in that class.